# Parameters in Vue Bootstrap table are not passed to events

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I am using Vue-bootstrap, according to the documentation (event, index and item) get passed by default to events with row-clicked, it doesn't happen in my case.

Here I wrote the b-table code and the event handler. Live code https://codesandbox.io/s/x77r1lwrlz

```
<b-table
        striped
        hover
        :items="trips"
        :fields="fields"
        @row-clicked="row(event);"
      />


 methods: {
    row: function( event) {
      console.log(event);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you try this: @row-clicked="row"

Comment: @latovic thank you, it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

By changing `row()` to `row` it works. Thanks to @latovic